# How can I use the Litecoin testnet?

Tags: litecoin, testnet, litecoin-qt, blockchain-explorer

Is there any Litecoin testnet explorer which records Litecoin testnet transactions? Where can a Litecoin testnet wallet be downloaded? Any reference or step by step explanation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Download [Litecoin Core](https://litecoin.org/), install it,  and start it with the `-testnet` option.

I'm aware of two Litecoin testnet explorers:

- http://testnet.litecointools.com/
- https://chain.so/testnet/ltc

Comment: This is only good for users who have 25GB to spare on their hard drive...  If you want to play around with the testnet create a wallet on https://block.io

Comment: @palebone: That would be a great start of your own answer! :)

Comment: doesn't look like I can answer with just my starting bonus rep

Answer (score 0):

https://chain.so/ltc
https://chain.so/testnet/ltc

Litecoin testnet block explorer

Comment: I'm confused that this answer was accepted. The main question appears to be about getting a testnet wallet, which doesn't get covered here.